# Generating custom GraphLayout for a hyperbolic graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, hyperbolic

I have code that generates a Matrix `Mat` (`Mat =` [data](https://pastebin.com/bTtguLL2)) that, when the graph is plotted, `AdjacencyGraph[Mat]` gives a graph.

Now, there are many inbuilt functions for `GraphLayout`. Once we fix a particular `GraphLayout`. For a particular `GraphLayout`, we get the vertex coordinates when we use `GraphEmbedding`.

Let us take a simple example if I have a matrix for a square geometry (square lattice). Then its graph will have a square face. Following the previous paragraph strategy, I will get the coordinates for the vertices like `{{0,0}, {0,1},...{0,Lx},...{Ly,Lx}}`, where `Lx` and `Ly` is the number of vertices along `x` and `y`. That is related to the size of the matrix, which is `(Lx X Ly) X (Lx X Ly)`. One can do this for honeycomb or triangle lattices.

However, my graph has higher connectivity that doesn't fall in the above case (meaning it's not Euclidean). Suppose I use the existing `GraphLayout`. Then the coordinates are not as per the hyperbolic plane. For instance, if I use the `GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"` then it uses the particular mechanism (minimizing the spring energy, not important here) to have a graph layout. But it starts to be a problem if I plot different (hyperbolic) graphs, where it is fully messed up and doesn't look good. So I can't extract coordinates rightly.

As an input, I will give the matrix with particular connectivity between the vertices. For example, below, I give as an input a lattice `{8,3}` in the matrix form, which is a polygon with 8 sides, and at each vertex, three such polygons (octagon) meet. As an output, I want the coordinates for all the vertices so that the coordinates satisfy a hyperbolic distance formula `distance[z1,z2]`. In other words, it is a fixed distance with a hyperbolic metric. So is there a way to create a custom `GraphLayout` that does it?

On idea from my side. Maybe we can create an `EdgeWeight` that encodes the distance function that, in turn, dictates how two edges should be connected? (no idea how good it is, maybe not at all)

**MWE**:

```
Mat = data;
graphMat = GraphEmbedding[AdjacencyGraph[ConnectMat, VertexCoordinates -> Coords, VertexLabels -> None, ImageSize -> Large, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]
 distance[z1_, z2_] :=  1./2 ArcCosh[1 + (2 Abs[z1 - z2]^2)/((1 - Abs[z1]^2) (1 - Abs[z2]^2))];
```

[image: Graph for the above data]

Update: Can we use the `EdgeWeight` function, perhaps? Where this `EdgeWeight` account for the hyperbolic distance?
One example from Euclidean (not exactly what want though using ChatGPT)

```
g = GridGraph[{10, 10}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 


EdgeWeight -> Range[1, 4 - 1/60, 1./60], 
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];

distance[v1_, v2_] := Norm[v1 - v2];

calculateLayout[g_, distance_] := 
  Module[{vertices, edges, layout}, vertices = VertexList[g];
   edges = EdgeList[g];
   layout = 
    AssociationThread[vertices, 
     Flatten[Outer[List, Range[10], Range[10]], 1]];
   Do[With[{v1 = First[edge], v2 = Last[edge]}, 
     While[distance[layout[v1], layout[v2]] > 
       PropertyValue[{g, edge}, EdgeWeight], 
      layout[v2] += 0.01*(layout[v1] - layout[v2])]], {edge, edges}];
   layout];

layout = calculateLayout[g, distance];

ambush = 
 Graph[g,(*VertexCoordinates->layout,*)VertexLabels -> "Name"(*,
  EdgeLabels->"EdgeWeight"*)]

GraphEmbedding[ambush]
```

I would have rather wanted to have the coordinates look like the values on the `Edge` instead of the original coordinates.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. From what I can tell you are asking to do multidimensional scaling in hyperbolic space, but it's not clear at all. Please explain better what you want to achieve. What is your input data, what is the specific output you want?

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry for getting back late! Sure! Let me paraphrase the statement to make it more clear. Just to say few words to make it little clear to you: I have a Adjacency matrix that has the information of how each nodes (or vertices) are connected to each other. However, this connectivity only exists in hyperbolic space (negatively curved) but if one tries to embed it in Euclidean palne their are distortions (where the edges look smaller if far from origin).

Comment: @Szabolcs In order to resovel this problem, I want to get the coordinates for each vertices with a particular metric (Poincaré metric) such that the cooridnates are not of Euclidean type (which will we wrong) by hyperbolic type (that is embedded on a Euclidean plane with the above metric).

Comment: @Szabolcs I edited my question to answer your question as clearly as I can. Please have a look :) Let me know if I need to make it clear more. Infinite thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _"the coordinates satisfy a hyperbolic distance formula"_? Perhaps you want to say that the distance between each neighbouring vertices should be **1** but calculated with **hyperbolic metric**?

Comment: @Domen Exactly! It is a fixed distance in a hyperbolic metric. I'm not sure if it is one, but a constant

Comment: So it sounds like you are looking to place vertices in hyperbolic space in such a way that the distance of connected vertices will be approximately the same as the weight of their connecting edge. Did I get this right? If yes, there's nothing built into Mathematica for this, and implementing something isn't a trivial undertaking. You could try to generalize one of the known force-directed layout algorithms to hyperbolic space.  A google search for "force directed layout hyperbolic" reveals multiple attempts, which you can use as starting points.

Comment: IMO this isn't really a Mathematica question, so perhaps not the best fit here. It's an interesting question and we did get nice answers for similar questions in the past, but I suspect that a usable implementation wouldn't be concise enough to fit an answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs, you are somewhat right! I want to place vertices in Euclidean space only but with a hyperbolic metric. Maybe this is what you meant by "weight of their connecting edge".

Comment: I am wondering if maybe generating the rule for this edge weight (as you mentioned) can solve this problem. For me this `EdgeWeight` will be encoding the metric, isn't it? Can then I take the coordinates systematically?

Comment: I just realized the `EdgeWeight` is not reflected in the position of the vertices. Then what I said is not going to work. I added a new MWE (using ChatGPT) to show this but you probably know it very well.

Comment: First, if you want the embedding algorithm to use `EdgeWeight`, you have to [enable it manually](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/method/SpringEmbedding.html#1757724783). Second, I don't think you can modify the `"SpringEmbedding"` in any way to account for your metric because you cannot redefine the energy function, and using `EdgeWeight`s will not help because your metric is not translationally invariant. Third, you can try writing your own embedding algorithm – it is in principle just a very simple minimizator (like `FindMinimum`) with a scoring function being ...

Comment: ... the same as in spring embedding, but using a custom distance function instead of Euclidean norm. I was experimenting with it, but did not manage to get good results. Mainly, one of the problem is that you seem to not know the actual hyperbolic distance you want to impose to the edges (_"I'm not sure if it is one, but a constant"_). Lastly, I suggest you try reading some literature on this topic; there seems to be [several papers](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+embedding+hyperbolic+metric) published.

Comment: Infinite thanks, @Domen !
I think I can forget about the `EdgeWeight` completely as you also mentioned it clearly. Now, the part about writing my own minimizator with a scoring function looks very interesting. I have no idea about it, but I need to do some research. However, I can provide you with the right distance for the above case, maybe then you want to try it? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure if the following is close to what you need, but the pretty pictures it can produce might be of interest.

We define a graph function that takes five arguments and `Graph` options.

The first argument controls the number of vertices of seed  polygon, the second argument controls the rotation/reflections transformations, the third integer specifies the number of iterations, the fourth argument  specifies the projection model as [Poincare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) or [Beltrami-Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model), the fifth argument controls tolerance used in rationalizing coordinates.
The helper functions `indexCoords`, `hCoords`, `getVertexCoords`, `getEdgeList`  and `poincareESF` are defined in the Code section below.

```
hyperbolicGraph[n_, m_, iter_ : 1, 
   layout : (Automatic | "Poincare" | "Beltrami") : "Poincare", pr_ : Automatic, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; (1/n + 1/m < 1/2) := 
 Module[{vl, el, vc,
    coords = indexCoords @ hCoords[n, m, iter, 
      layout, pr /. Automatic -> 10^-5]}, 
  vc = getVertexCoords @ coords; 
  el = getEdgeList @ coords; 
  vl = Range @ Length @ vc;
  Graph[vl, el, VertexCoordinates -> vc,
    EdgeShapeFunction -> poincareESF, opts]]
```

#### Examples

**Note:** ***Before using `hyperbolicGraph`, you need to copy and execute the code in the `Code` section  below.***

```
Row[hyperbolicGraph[8, 3, 3, #, Automatic, 
    VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["n = 8 | m = 3 | iterations = 3 | layout : " <> #, 16], 
    ImageSize -> Large] & /@ {"Poincare", "Beltrami"}]
```

[image]

Replace `3` in the second argument with `7` to get:

[image]

Playing with `Graph` options for styling edges and vertices:

```
n = 8; m = 3;

table = Table[With[{ge = GraphEmbedding[#]}, 
  SetProperty[#,
   {EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> Directive[Red, Opacity[.6], 
      AbsoluteThickness[(1.1 - N @ Norm[Mean @ ge[[{e[[1]], e[[-1]]}]]]) 30], 
         CapForm["Round"]]}, 
      VertexStyle -> {v_ :> {Yellow, 
          AbsolutePointSize[(1.1 - N@Norm[ge[[v]]]) 25]}}}]] & @
  hyperbolicGraph[n, m, it, lo, Automatic, 
     PlotLabel -> Style[it, White, 16], 
     VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge", 
     EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> 
        Directive[Opacity[.6], RandomColor[], CapForm["Round"]]}, 
     ImageSize -> 350, Background -> Black], 
 {lo, {"Poincare", "Beltrami"}}, {it, {0, 1, 2, 3}}];

Labeled[Grid[MapThread[Prepend]@
   {table, Style[Rotate[#, 90 Degree], 24] & /@ {"Poincare", "Beltrami"}}],
 Style[StringForm["  n = `` | m = `` | iterations = {0, 1, 2, 3}", n, m], 24], 
 {{Top, Left}}]
```

[image]

Further examples:

```
n = 3; layout = Automatic;

Grid[{hyperbolicGraph[n, 7, #, layout, Automatic, 
     ImageSize -> 200] & /@ Range[4], 
  hyperbolicGraph[n, 50, #, layout, Automatic, 
     ImageSize -> 200] & /@ Range[4]}]
```

[image]

With `layout = "Beltrami"` we get

[image]

With `n = 4; layout = Automatic;` we get

[image]

With `n = 4; layout = "Beltrami";` we get

[image]

```
Column[Table[
  Row[hyperbolicGraph[8, 3, #, layout, Automatic, ImageSize -> 400, 
     VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", 
     VertexStyle -> Directive[Orange, PointSize[Small]]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}],
  {layout, {Automatic, "Beltrami"}}]]
```

[image]

---

#### Code

First, several functions for generation and transformations of lists of coordinates (these are slightly modified versions of functions I found inspecting the function `` GraphComputation`RegularHyperbolicTilingGraphGraphComputation`RegularHyperbolicTilingGraph ``):

```
ClearAll[hyperbolicRotation, hyperbolicReflection, growCoords,  seedCoords,
  hCoords, hyperbolicGraph]

hyperbolicRotation[z_, {c_, t_}] := 
 With[{w = ((z - c) E^(I t))/(1 - z Conjugate[c])},
   (c + w)/(1 +  w Conjugate[c])] 

hyperbolicReflection[coords_, n_, m_] /; (1/n + 1/m < 1/2) := 
 Nest[Append[#, hyperbolicRotation[#[[-2]], {#[[-1]], 2 π/m}]] &, coords, n - 2]

seedCoords[n_, m_] /; (1/n + 1/m < 1/2) := 
 Block[{r, v, s = Sin[π/n]^2  Sec[π/m]^2}, r = s/(1 - s); 
  v = Sqrt[1 + 2 r - 2 Sqrt[r (1 + r)] Sin[π (1/n + 1/m)]] Exp[I π/n ]; 
  NestList[hyperbolicRotation[#, {0, -2 π/n }] &, v, n - 1]]

growCoords[coords_, m_] := With[{n = Length[coords]}, 
  Map[hyperbolicReflection[#, n, m] &] @ Reverse[Partition[coords, 2, 1, 1], 2]]
```

We use the above functions to generate a nested list of coordinates:

```
hCoords[n_, m_, k_, op : (Automatic | "Poincare" | "Beltrami") : "Poincare", 
   pr_ : Automatic ] /; (1/n + 1/m < 1/2) := 
 Module[{opr = op /. 
   {Automatic | "Poincare" ->  Identity, 
   "Beltrami" -> (2 #/(1 + Abs[#]^2) &)}}, 
  Rationalize[Map[ReIm @* opr, 
    NestList[p |-> Flatten[growCoords[#, m] & /@ p, 1],
    {N @ seedCoords[n, m]}, k], {2}], pr /. Automatic -> 10^-5]]
```

Next, a few operators to get the edge list, vertex list and vertex coordinates from  the coordinate list produced by `hCoords`:

```
indexCoords = Association @* DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort @* First] @* 
  (Thread[ArrayComponents[#, 2] -> #] &) @* Last;

getEdgeList = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort] @* Apply[Join] @*
   Map[MapApply[UndirectedEdge]@Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] &] @* Keys;

getVertexCoords = DeleteDuplicates @* Apply[Join] @* KeyValueMap[Thread[#->#2]&];
```

For hyperbolic lines and segments we use the function `` GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`geo ``

```
GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart;

poincareESF = GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`geo[.99 First[#], .99 Last[#], 
    "segment"] &;

poincareLine = GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`geo[.99 First[#], .99 Last[#], 
    "line"] &;
```

We now have all the pieces to define `hyperbolicGraph`:

```
hyperbolicGraph[n_, m_, iter_ : 1, 
   layout : (Automatic | "Poincare" | "Beltrami") : "Poincare", pr_ : Automatic, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; (1/n + 1/m < 1/2) := 
 Module[{vl, el, vc,
    coords = indexCoords @ hCoords[n, m, iter, 
      layout, pr /. Automatic -> 10^-5]}, 
  vc = getVertexCoords @ coords; 
  el = getEdgeList @ coords; 
  vl = Range @ Length @ vc;
  Graph[vl, el, VertexCoordinates -> vc,
    EdgeShapeFunction -> poincareESF, opts]]
```

---

#### Poincare lines and segments

```
SeedRandom[12];
rp = RandomPoint[Disk[], {5, 2}];
colors = RandomColor[5];

Row[{Graphics[{Red, Circle[], Blue, PointSize[Large], 
    MapThread[{#, Point@#2} &]@{colors, rp}}, ImageSize -> 400],
  Graphics[{Red, Circle[], CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[8], 
    Orange, poincareESF /@ rp, Gray, AbsoluteThickness[1], 
    poincareLine /@ rp, Blue, PointSize[Large], 
    MapThread[{#, Point@#2} &]@{colors, rp}}, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

---

#### Fun with `hCoords`:

```
n = 3; m = 8;

Row[Graphics[{RandomColor[], Polygon @ #} & /@ 
   Flatten[hCoords[n, m, 4, #], 1], ImageSize -> 400] & /@ 
    {"Poincare", "Beltrami"}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

With `n = 7; m = 3;` we get

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Can we get the adjacency matrix at a fixed iteration(e.g., it=2) from these results?

Comment: use `AdjacencyMatrix @ hyperbolicGraph[3, 7, 2]`?

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @kglr! Sorry for the late response. I thought no will answer it. Here is your beautiful answer! I tried to run your code but I think I'm making some mistakes. [I'm getting errors](https://imgur.com/dk9TsQe) instead of beautiful plots.

Comment: Shamina, looks like you did not copy all functions in `Code` section.

Comment: I did it, it works super nicely! I have one question. Can I get the coordinates of the vertices for a particular iteration? For instance, for `hyperbolicGraph[8, 3, 2]`?

Comment: use `GraphEmbedding@hyperbolicGraph[8, 3, 2] `?