# "RegularHyperbolicTilingGraph" Does Not Work Properly

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, geometry, visualization

I am trying to draw regular hyperbolic tesselations using the "RegularHyperbolicTilingGraph" function on Mathematica 13. Here is the introduction of this function on the repository: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RegularHyperbolicTilingGraph/

I'm trying to run one line of code from the repository that should output something like this:

```
Table[ResourceFunction["RegularHyperbolicTilingGraph"][6, 4, k, 
  GraphLayout -> "Poincare", WorkingPrecision -> 20], {k, 4}]
```

[image]

But when I run the code on my computer it gives something like this:
[image]

which looks wrong. How can I fix this? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Indeed this seems like a bug – it works normally for me in 12.3 (Windows), but gives the same (wrong) result as yours in 13.3.0 (Cloud). You should report this to WRI: There is a link _Send a message about this function_ in the bottom of the [documentation page](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RegularHyperbolicTilingGraph/). Let us know if you report this problem, otherwise someone else can do it instead :)

Comment: closely related Q/A: [Generating custom GraphLayout for a hyperbolic graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285781/125)